# Is it a good practice to share member variables among unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a unit test class like below,

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest {

    private static final int MY_CONSTANT = 7;
    private String expectedValue = "expected value";

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        int value = 50; // get by processing
        int ans = value / MY_CONSTANT ; 
        String actual = "actual string"; // get by processing
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        int value = 40; // get by processing
        int ans = value / MY_CONSTANT ; 
        String actual = "actual string 2"; // get by processing
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedValue, actual);
    }

}
```

And one would write it like below,

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class MyTest { 

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        int value = 50; // get by processing
        int ans = value / 7 ; 
        String actual = "actual string"; // get by processing
        Assert.assertEquals("expected value", actual);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        int value = 40; // get by processing
        int ans = value / 7 ; 
        String actual = "actual string 2"; // get by processing
        Assert.assertEquals("expected value", actual);
    }

}
```

Both will work fine, But is it a good practice to share member variables among unit test methods like that ?

What is the best way to do it from the above two ?

Comment: If its a constant declare as static final, if the intention is to change it in one method so it is a bad idea

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos So If its a constant declare as static final, it is fine ?

Comment: it really doesn't matter: IMHO you are overthinking this one :)

Comment: @giorgiga may be :D anyway edit the question a bit, what is your preferred way on this ?

Comment: @prime yes, no problem, but use a good name so when reading the code you dont need to consult the value of the constant

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos that might be the reason I like to write tests in the second way I have mentioned. Feel like it has all what it needs to have within the tests itself.

Comment: probably the second is better, since rarely you will expect the same result in more than one test, and adding a constant for each unique result will just take space

Answer (score 3):

Sure, if the shared values are *immutable*. Regardless of language/testing framework, it's generally not a good idea to share *mutable* values between tests. That might constrain you to running the tests in a specific order, or require you to run certain tests that mutate the value before running dependent tests.

Another consideration is that sharing constant values between tests could possibly make them more brittle or harder to maintain as code changes. It introduces what might be unnecessary coupling between the tests.

A good question to ask yourself is *what are the tradeoffs I'm making?* If it's just defining a constant for an assertion, then I'd probably not do that unless the value was burdensome to define in each test.