# why is bad to avoid introducing shared state in test classes?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

I was reading a book on unit testing, below is denoted as bad code in the book:

```
public class CustomerTests
{
   private Store _store;

   [Fact]
   public void Test1()
   {
      //act 
      _store = new Store(5);
      ...
   }

   [Fact]
   public void Test2()
   {
      //act 
      _store = new Store(100);
      ...
   }
}
```

As we know that when xUnit or other testing frameworks, a new instance of test class is created(constructor runs before each test in the class) for each test, so in my example, since I have two test methods, so there are two instances of `CustomerTests`, since they are different object/instance, so `_store` instance/property in different instance are therefore also independent, which means one test methods modifies its `_store`, the other `_store` in other instance is not affected. So they technically are not "shared state", why we need to avoid that?

Comment: It is bad code, because it did not even compile ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo  I removed the readonly

Comment: 1) they're not sharing state assuming this isn't **concurrent**, each test is creating it's own instance of `Store`. Though you probably could have gone with a local variable here 2) If xunit supports concurrent testing of methods of the same class you run into threading issues 3) more importantly, tests should be simple otherwise you need to make tests to test the tests. You're not creating another system here so it's fine to copy-paste code. Each test should be independent

Comment: You can put `_store` creation into constructor, also further reading https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context

Comment: _or other testing frameworks_ - this is not totally correct. NUnit for example creates one instance for all test methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a good practice to share member variables among unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706008/is-it-a-good-practice-to-share-member-variables-among-unit-tests)